# Can I customize "Select All" in NSOutlineViews?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

Right now "Select All" (Apple Key + A) is selecting all rows in the table.

Can I customise this option in order to select only the items contained in a specific parent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved very easily by overriding selectAll: in the NSOutlineView subclass.